# Transform XML to XML using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

As i said earlier I have started learning XSLT

When I am working on that I getting an wrong type of XML Format

Input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<testingconfig note-ref="no">
<access-panel>113AL</access-panel>
<access-panel>119AL</access-panel>
</testingcongif>
```

Output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<testingconfig>
<panel><panelid>113AL</panelid></panel> 
<panel><panelid>119AL</panelid></panel> 
</testingconfig>
```

My XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<testingconfig>
    <xsl:for-each select="testingconfig">
    <panel>
        <panelid>
            <xsl:value-of select="*"/>
        </panelid>
    </panel>
</xsl:for-each>
</testingconfig>
```

Out put for this is

```
<testingconfig>
<panel>
    <panelid>
        113AL 119AL
    </panelid>
</panel>
</testingconfig>
```

Can any one help me here where i am doing mistake and pls help me how to do it in XSLT 2.0

Pls help me

Thanks & Regards
M

Comment: I am not sure that it is right just to post a solution, so it is better to read http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply 

This is actually sample 

i will convert the original

Comment: Both your source XML document and the wanted results aren't well-formed (I edited and corrected the former). Also, you haven't accepted the good answer you got -- please learn to do this (hint: by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer).

Comment: Hi thk u very much for the reply

Comment: Hi Dimitre

I am new to this site I was not aware what to do ?

Sorry for not clicking the check-mark 

Thanks for the reply I have started reading XSLT day ago

Regards
M

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just break it down into a set of transformation rules. For example:

```
<xsl:template match="testingfig">
  <tscon><xsl:value-of select="."/></tscon>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="config">
   <testingvalue>
       <testingtype>mar</testingtype>
       <testid>mar<xsl:value-of select="."/></testid>
   </testingvalue>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I'm a bit concerned that by giving you these examples I'm leading you by the hand into a swamp where you will get quickly stuck. It seems to me from your question that you are right at the beginning of learning this language, and asking on a forum for a solution to one simple problem is not really the best learning strategy. You can't learn a programming language by trial and error, or by copying noddy examples. You need to go away and read some books or tutorials.

Comment: If I want to transform one XML structure to another, what references would you suggest to lean how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <testingconfig>
        <xsl:for-each select="testingconfig/access-panel">
        <panel><panelid><xsl:value-of select="." /></panelid></panel>

        </xsl:for-each>
    </testingconfig>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```